# Hard coding bin locations on a ggplot2 heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to hard code the bin locations to match 9 rectangles inside the geom_rect and ignore all results outside of the rectangle.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Replace directory below
pitcher_data <- read.csv("stackoverflow.csv")

ggplot(data = pitcher_data, aes(x = PlateLocSide, y = PlateLocHeight)) +
  ylim(0, 4) +
  xlim(-3, 3) +
  geom_bin2d(aes(fill = stat(count)), binwidth = c(0.8, 0.6)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3661ad", "white", "#d82129"),
                       values = c(0, .5, 1)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.4, xend = -0.4, y = 1.3, yend = 3.1), color = "lightgray", linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.4, xend = 0.4, y = 1.3, yend = 3.1), color = "lightgray", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -1.20, xend = 1.20, y = 1.9, yend = 1.9), color = "lightgray", linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = -1.20, xend = 1.20, y = 2.5, yend = 2.5), color = "lightgray", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_rect(xmin = -1.20, xmax = 1.20, ymin = 1.30, ymax = 3.1, show.legend = FALSE, fill = "transparent", color = "black") +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Plate Side (ft)") +
  ylab("Plate Height (ft)") +
  labs(fill = "Count", title = "Pitch Heatmap") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 2)
```

[Google Sheet CSV link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c5qMfol-WM3AvCOZIrgnghfMM-9Hh3UZ-PRN0dgivL8/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried to adjust the bin width and length but it was just adjusting them from the existing location and wasn't moving them as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could bin manually using `cut` or `findInterval` then use `geom_tile`

```r
library(tidyverse)

pitcher_data %>%
  mutate(bin_x = findInterval(PlateLocSide, c(-1.2, -0.4, 0.4, 1.2)) + 1,
         bin_x = c(-0.8, 0, 0.8)[bin_x],
         bin_y = findInterval(PlateLocHeight, c(1.3, 1.9, 2.5, 3.1)) + 1,
         bin_y = c(1.6, 2.2, 2.8)[bin_y]) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  group_by(bin_x, bin_y) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = bin_x, y = bin_y, fill = count)) +
  ylim(0, 4) +
  xlim(-3, 3) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3661ad", "white", "#d82129"),
                       values = c(0, .5, 1)) +
  annotate("segment", color = "lightgray", linetype = "dashed",
           x = c(-0.4, 0.4, -1.2, -1.2),
           xend = c(-0.4,0.4, 1.2, 1.2), 
           y = c(1.3, 1.3, 1.9, 2.5),
           yend = c(3.1, 3.1, 1.9, 2.5)) + 
  geom_rect(xmin = -1.20, xmax = 1.20, ymin = 1.30, ymax = 3.1, 
            show.legend = FALSE, fill = "transparent", color = "black") +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Plate Side (ft)") +
  ylab("Plate Height (ft)") +
  labs(fill = "Count", title = "Pitch Heatmap") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: If I overlay the points over the zones the colors and key aren't necessarily true though as there are more than 5 in the top left 

https://imgur.com/a/jThqHy3

It may be only counting points fully in the zone? ->
Is it possible to count a point if over 50% of it falls in the zone?

Comment: @Mason mathematically a point has zero width and zero height, so by definition it can only be inside or outside - it only _looks_ like some of them are partially inside because they are being drawn as little circles on your plot. If you make the point size smaller you will see that they are all either inside or outside. Conversely, if you make the points big enough (huge circles) they would _all_ cross some boundaries. If your "points" are actually circles with a known diameter, then the approach will have to be different (and you need to know the diameter)